# Ubuntu 14.04 failed to download repository informations

Tags: upgrade, repository, downloads

**Context :**
I'm not able anymore to connect on my wifi network a work, however at home all is fine. I decided to check if there was some upgrades and Ubuntu tells me "failed to download repository informations".
[Here a little pic to illustrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdhXS.png).
Could someone help me with this ?

In order to help, here the result of `LANG=C sudo apt-get update` :

```
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417) trusty InRelease
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417) trusty Release.gpg
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417) trusty Release
Err cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417) trusty/main amd64 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Err cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417) trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Err cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417) trusty/main i386 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Err cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417) trusty/restricted i386 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417) trusty/main Translation-en
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417) trusty/main Translation-fr
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417) trusty/restricted Translation-en
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417) trusty/restricted Translation-fr
Ign http://repo.mongodb.org trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 InRelease                   
Ign http://liveusb.info all InRelease                                          
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       
Ign http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://liveusb.info all Release.gpg                                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://apt.postgresql.org trusty-pgdg InRelease                            
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Hit http://liveusb.info all Release                                            
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                      
Hit http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr trusty InRelease                                    
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources                    
Hit http://liveusb.info all/main Sources                                       
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Sources                        
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
Hit http://deb.playonlinux.com precise InRelease                               
Hit http://liveusb.info all/main amd64 Packages                                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources              
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://liveusb.info all/main i386 Packages                                 
Hit http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr trusty/main Sources                                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                               
Get:1 https://get.docker.com docker InRelease                                  
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr trusty/main amd64 Packages                          
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages                  
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources                   
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr trusty/main i386 Packages                           
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Ign https://get.docker.com docker InRelease                                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en                 
Hit http://repo.mongodb.org trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 Release.gpg                 
Hit https://get.docker.com docker Release.gpg                                  
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources             
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit https://get.docker.com docker Release                                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Sources                        
Hit https://get.docker.com docker/main amd64 Packages                          
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources               
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit https://get.docker.com docker/main i386 Packages                           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages       
Hit http://apt.postgresql.org trusty-pgdg/main amd64 Packages                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Get:2 https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources             
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Ign http://liveusb.info all/main Translation-en                                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages                  
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages            
Ign http://liveusb.info all/main Translation-fr                                
Hit http://repo.mongodb.org trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 Release                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages       
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages      
Hit http://apt.postgresql.org trusty-pgdg/main i386 Packages                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages        
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://repo.mongodb.org trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse amd64 Packages   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages         
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-en                          
Hit http://deb.playonlinux.com precise/main amd64 Packages                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages       
Ign https://get.docker.com docker/main Translation-fr                          
Hit http://deb.playonlinux.com precise/main i386 Packages                      
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-fr                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://repo.mongodb.org trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse i386 Packages    
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Ign http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr trusty/main Translation-en                          
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 Packages               
Ign http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr trusty/main Translation-fr                          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free i386 Packages                
Ign http://repo.mongodb.org trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse Translation-en   
Ign http://repo.mongodb.org trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse Translation-fr   
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources           
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ InRelease                                    
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages          
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages     
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en          
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com trusty InRelease                                
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com trusty/main Sources                             
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release.gpg                                  
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                      
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages              
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com trusty/main i386 Packages                       
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages               
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Get:3 https://deb.nodesource.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-fr                    
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-fr              
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release                                      
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-fr                            
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-fr              
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-fr                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-fr                        
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-fr                            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-fr            
Ign http://apt.postgresql.org trusty-pgdg/main Translation-en      
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-fr
Ign http://apt.postgresql.org trusty-pgdg/main Translation-fr
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Packages                                     
Ign http://deb.playonlinux.com precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://deb.playonlinux.com precise/main Translation-fr
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-fr
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com trusty/main Translation-en                      
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com trusty/main Translation-fr                
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Translation-en                         
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Translation-fr
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/themuso/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/themuso/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Open a terminal, run the command `LANG=C sudo apt-get update` and add the output by [edit]ing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the PPA `ppa:themuso/ppa` enabled but this PPA has no packages for Trusty.
Therefore remove it by executing:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:themuso/ppa
```

To avoid the second error `Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu …`, disable the entry `deb cdrom…`

```
sudo sed -i 's/\(^deb cdrom.*\)/#\1/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Now start

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and enjoy **:)**

Comment: Now you could accept the answer with the check mark on the left side of the answer **;)**